# having difficulty using twitter api command implemention in python

Tags: python, api, twitter, encoding, implementation

I am trying to implement this into python:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweeters/ids

here is what I have so far:

```
def reqs():
t = Twitter(auth=OAuth('...'))
tweets = t.statuses.user_timeline.snl()
```

How do I get the user id's of those who retweeted a single tweet from the user's timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use tweeters instead. boom. figured it out on my own

```
t.statuses.retweets(....)
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

So after you would do this

```
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(...))

tweets = t.statuses.user_timeline.snl()

for tweet in tweets:
    retweets = t.statuses.retweets_of_me(since_id=str(tweet['id']), max_id=str(tweet['id']))
    idList.append(retweets)
```

After this all you would have to just go through `idList`, and find the ids that only appear once in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but someone else gave me this answer too. Using retweets_of_me gives me an error:

{"errors":[{"message":"Rate limit exceeded","code":88}]}

that is why i wanted to use retweeters, but I do not know how

Comment: That just means that you have called the api too much, you will have to wait for an hour so your limit resets. [Explanation](https://blog.twitter.com/2008/what-does-rate-limit-exceeded-mean-updated)

Comment: I did this yesterday too, but all i got were empty brackets and then the same error msg. Also retweets_of_me gets the tweets, I need the id's (usernames) of the users who retweeted a particular tweet.

Comment: So in summary I need to do:

input -> retweeters(tweet ID)

output -> ['username1','username2','username3','username4',]

Answer (score 0):

Please see my solution at this post: [difficulty using twitter api command implemention in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172169/difficulty-using-twitter-api-command-implemention-in-python)

It does use the Twyton API, however.