# retweeters python twitter api implementation

Tags: python, api, twitter, compiler-errors, implementation

using python, how do I get an array of all users who retweeted a tweet. I found this, but do not know how to implement it into python.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweeters/ids

here is the code i tried

```
 t = Twitter(auth=OAuth('....'))
 tweets = t.statuses.user_timeline.AIG_Latestnews()

When I try this:
pl = t.statuses.retweeters(tweets[0]['id'])

I get an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#134>", line 1, in <module>
    reqs()
  File "C:\Documents and     Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\twitter_travel_guard.py", line 138, in reqs
pl = t.statuses.retweeters(tweets[0]['id'])
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: I posted example code for doing this with Twython here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172169/difficulty-using-twitter-api-command-implemention-in-python

Answer (score 0):

figured it out on my own

pl = t.statuses.retweets.id(id=tw)
print pl[0]['user']['screen_name']